# WSO2 CARBON DEPLOY BPS

Tags: deployment, wso2, wso2-esb

I' ve just started to use wso2 developer studio and i have been able to make everything working thanks to this sample ([BankingSample](http://wso2.org/project/developer-studio/2.0.1/docs/banking_sample.html)).

Now, i would like to know if is possible, instead of using different servers as AS, DSS, ESB and BPS (like explained in this example), to deploy everything on a single server (WSO2 Carbon for instance)..i' ve already added all server roles like this in Carbon.xml

```
<ServerRoles>
<Role>CarbonServer</Role>
<Role>EnterpriseServiceBus</Role>
<Role>BusinessProcessServer</Role>
<Role>ApplicationServer</Role>
<Role>DataServicesServer</Role>
</ServerRoles>
```

but this is not enough, since it' s not working..i think there's something concerning the transports in axis2.xml file, and different IN/OUT transports compared to esb's axis2.xml configuration file.

So i tried to mix things up a little bit, copying some of esb's configurations in carbon's one (for example not blocking 8280 port), but it' s still not working
Any idea on how to make this correctly working ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the features of each server. Please follow this blog [1]

[1]http://dileepajayakody.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-features-via-feature.html

Comment: First of all thanks for answering..I've installed all the needed features..now,i would like to know if i have to use NIO Transport Receivers, and so uncomment some lines in axis2.xml file to get the sample working (since the sample use the 8280 port and if i don't change anything, i got connection refused exception). Thanks for helping

Comment: i' ve been trying to solve this, but maybe it's simply impossible to get everything working like i' m doing..i' ve tried to uncomment the Multiple Istance Scenario both in IN/OUT transport and i got `ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.PartnerService} -  Error sending message to Axis2 for ODE mex {PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphr81a8xva8xu7 [PID {http://wso2.org/sample/banking}AccountOpeningProcess-2] calling org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@1f3f00af.op1(...) Status REQUEST}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.`

Comment: If i uncomment only the part in IN TRANSPORTS, it starts working but then i got `ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.transport.OutTransportInfo`..so is it correct, it' s impossible to get the sample working using just wso2 carbon as server?..i don' t know if i' missing something, or i' m just trying to do something impossible to do